# How to split df column into many rows and counts (long df) Python / pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have this df with these values (head (5)) that has these characteristics (df.info ()) and I need to create a column for each existing amenities in df.amenities that contains 0 or 1 (0 = absent, 1 = present), I am new to this so I am not sure how to proceed.

```
accomodates_list = (2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0)

amenities_list = amenities_list = ['{"Cable TV","Wireless Internet","Air conditioning","Free parking on premises",Breakfast,"Pets live on this property",Cat(s),"Indoor fireplace",Heating,"Smoke detector","Carbon monoxide detector","Fire extinguisher",Essentials,Shampoo,Hangers,"Hair dryer",Iron,"translation missing: en.hosting_amenity_49","translation missing: en.hosting_amenity_50"}' ,  '{TV,Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,Heating,"Family/kid friendly","Smoke detector","Carbon monoxide detector","First aid kit","Fire extinguisher",Essentials,Shampoo,Hangers,"Hair dryer",Iron}' ,  '{TV,"Cable TV",Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,"Free parking on premises",Heating,Washer,Dryer}','{TV,Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,"Free parking on premises","Buzzer/wireless intercom",Heating,"Family/kid friendly",Washer,Dryer,"Smoke detector","Carbon monoxide detector",Essentials,Shampoo,Hangers,"Hair dryer",Iron}' ,  '{Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,"Free parking on premises","Pets allowed",Gym,Heating,"Family/kid friendly","Smoke detector","Carbon monoxide detector","First aid kit",Essentials,"Laptop friendly workspace","translation missing: en.hosting_amenity_50"}']
    
df = pd.DataFrame({"accommodates":accomodates_list , "amenities":amenities_list})

     accommodates                                          amenities
        0           2.0  {"Cable TV","Wireless Internet","Air condition...
        1           4.0  {TV,Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditio...
        2           4.0  {TV,"Cable TV",Internet,"Wireless Internet","A...
        3           3.0  {TV,Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditio...
        4           4.0  {Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditionin...
```

and I need a result like this:

```
  accommodates                                          amenities  TV  \
0           2.0  {"Cable TV","Wireless Internet","Air condition...   0   
1           4.0  {TV,Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditio...   1   
2           4.0  {TV,"Cable TV",Internet,"Wireless Internet","A...   1   
3           3.0  {TV,Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditio...   1   
4           4.0  {Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditionin...   0   

   Cable TV  Internet  Wireless Internet  
0         1         0                  1  
1         0         1                  1  
2         1         1                  1  
3         0         1                  1  
4         0         1                  1
```

The amenities values are as I put here, there is a screenshot from the df where I stract these values:

[image]

Comment: `df.amenities.str.replace('\{|"|\}',"").str.get_dummies(',')`

Comment: your input data looks badly formatted.  longterm, you will do well to fix the formatting before import

Comment: @anon01, is not bad formatted, the dataset came like that (I put a screenshot from the original dataset)

Comment: @QuangHoang, it works! Thanks you so much!